# Deploying app with heroku and docker throws error when installing requirements

Tags: python, docker, heroku, scikit-learn

Hi I want to deploy a `dash app` that makes use of `scikit-learn` and `xgboost`. According to Heroku's [documentation](https://help.heroku.com/S48C2M3H/can-i-use-scientific-python-libraries-scipy-scikit-learn-etc-on-heroku) this should be possible using docker. I am following their approach as suggested on [github](https://github.com/heroku-examples/python-miniconda).

However, I receive an error after running the last step to deploy my app `heroku container:push web`.

```
(Project) C:\Users\Project\venv>heroku container:push web
=== Building web (C:\Users\Project\venv\Dockerfile)
Sending build context to Docker daemon  917.5kB
Step 1/7 : FROM heroku/miniconda
 ---> 8b1058516fe3
Step 2/7 : ADD ./webapp/requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
 ---> a3190f679660
Step 3/7 : RUN pip install -qr /tmp/requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 2e0f82c37221
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-XjwVjo/matplotlib/
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -qr /tmp/requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
 !    Error: docker build exited with Error: 1
```

My folder structure looks as follows:

```
venv/
   Dockerfile
   webapp/
       assets/
          style.css
       .gitignore
       data.csv
       Main.py --> Dash App
       models.py
       prepareDataSet.py
       requirements.txt
       wsgi.py
```

I am using `python 3.6.1`, `pip 19.3.1` & `setuptools 45.1.0`

IDK if this is helpful - my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM heroku/miniconda

# Grab requirements.txt.
ADD ./webapp/requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install -qr /tmp/requirements.txt

# Add our code
ADD ./webapp /opt/webapp/
WORKDIR /opt/webapp

RUN conda install scikit-learn xgboost

CMD gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT wsgi
```

Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In your Docker file, kindly declare your WORKDIR before running your requirements.txt file. Alternatively, you can run the requirements.txt file with this code snippet which worked for me.

```
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```